# how to prevent underscore template tag to be htmlencoded on jquery html select

Tags: jquery, html, underscore.js, html-entities

When I do this:

```
$(".two", '<div class="one"></div><div class="two"><%=abc%></div>').html();
```

the loaded html becomes:

```
&lt;%=abc%&gt;
```

How can I prevent this htmlentities conversion.

Thank you

Comment: You are viewing it in browser as `&lt;%=abc%&gt;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `replace(them)`:

```
$(".two", '<div class="one"></div><div class="two"><%=abc%></div>').html().replace('&lt;', "<").replace('&gt;', ">")
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owarad/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: Invoking `replace('&lt;','<')` only replaces the first instance of `'&lt;'`, use `replace(/&lt;/g,'<')` to replace all instances. (The first argument of `replace` is a regex, the `g` makes it a global replace)